# Indexing of variables in Python 3.5 with PuLP

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, pulp

I'm trying to make my code for a linear programming problem a bit more simple. What I have right now is:

```
normal_hours_laptop_01 = LpVariable('Hours for laptop in month 1', 0, 20000)
normal_hours_laptop_02 = LpVariable('Hours for laptop in month 2', 0, 20000)
normal_hours_laptop_03 = LpVariable('Hours for laptop in month 3', 0, 20000)
normal_hours_laptop_04 = LpVariable('Hours for laptop in month 4', 0, 20000)
```

and so on...

I would like to code it in a format like:

```
d = {}

for x in range(1,13):
    d["production_hours_laptop_{0}".format(x)] = LpVariable("Production hours for laptop in month {}".format(x)]
```

And then use these variables individually when needed, by calling them by their name with index number.

I can print the list with all variable names, but I can't use individual variables in calculations. Does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 d = {x: LpVariable("Production hours for laptop in month {}".format(x), 0, 2000) 
      for x in range(1, 13)}
```

Then `d[1]` is equal to the `LpVariable` for 1.  This technique is called dictionary comprehension.